# У пользователя admin нет прав администратора в Nexus OSS 3.34.0-01

Tags: nexus, artifactory

При входе в nexus с логином admin с паролем из `/opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password`. Нет прав на создание репозиториев, а в профиле пользователя username почему-то `anonymous`
Установку и настройку nexus-а делал по этой [статье](https://devopscube.com/how-to-install-latest-sonatype-nexus-3-on-linux/)

[image: Нет возможности управлять репозиториями]

Что упустил в настройке Nexus-а?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этим когда переделывал конфиг с https на http для тестирований.
В конфиге nginx в разделе **location /** забыл закомментировать строку **proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https"**